# Find out what foreign key is used in has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to write a gem that can include an automatic count for how many instances there is through a `has_many` relationship in a single sql query.

I would like the declaration to look like this

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, foreign_key: :foo_id
  can_count :bars
end
```

In order for me to make this work I would need a method like `Foo.bars_foreign_key` or something that would return `:foo_id`. Is this possible to achieve? Or should I go with the more simplistic approach and assume default foreign key and take custom foreign key as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [reflections](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html):

```
Foo.reflections[:bars].foreign_key.to_sym
# => :foo_id
```

Or something like this for all reflections:

```
ref_hash = {}
Foo.reflect_on_all_associations.each { |h| ref_hash[h.name] = h.foreign_key }
ref_hash
# => {:bar=>"foo_id", ...}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works with one minor tweak. `Foo.reflections` has strings not symbols as keys.

Comment: `Foo.reflections[:bars].foreign_key.to_sym # => :foo_id` :)

Comment: `Foo.reflections[:bars]` returns `nil`, `Foo.reflections['bars'].foreign_key` works. Was what I meant with my comment.